# Browser delay with changing content of the page in django admin (caching, python/django)

Tags: python, django, caching, django-admin, django-middleware

I have a bit weird problem witch caching on my project in django.

I can edit my page-content in django-admin. When i do that and refresh site - nothing is happening. I have to wait few minutes for changes. Funny thing is that, when i change browser (or computer) - i dont have to wait - the changes are on. Is it the problem of django, browser or what? Is it possible to set setting.py to get changes immediately?

By the way, i have already figured out that when i turn the 
"django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware" off - the problem disapears, but i dont want to turn cache off...

Any ideas?

Comment: Does anybody know how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you want to keep your site-wide cache on but you want to make sure that the cache gets cleared whenever your content is updated or added, you can implement a django signals to detect the add/update/delete event and clear the cache.

Django signals - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/

Here's a code snippet example:-

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=BlogPost)
def clear_cache(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.published_on is not None:
        cache.delete('feed')
```

In this example, whenever the BlogPost model is "saved" (added or updated), the `feed` key in the cache will be deleted.  In your case, you will have to implement `page-content` (something like this `cache.delete('page-content')` and decide which corresponding model will be your `sender` that triggers the clearing of the cache when it is being saved.