# Browser delay with changing content of the page in django admin (caching, middleware, python/django)

Tags: django, caching, django-admin, browser-cache, django-middleware

I have a bit weird problem witch caching on my project in django.

I can edit my page-content in django-admin. When i do that and refresh site - nothing is happening. I have to wait few minutes for changes. Funny thing is that, when i change browser (or computer) - i dont have to wait - the changes are on. Is it the problem of django, browser or what? Is it possible to set setting.py to get changes immediately?

By the way, i have already figured out that when i turn the "django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware" off - the problem disapears, but i dont want to turn cache off...

Any ideas?

Comment: This post is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692538/browser-delay-with-changing-content-of-the-page-in-django-admin-caching-python

Answer (score 1):

When you have cache middleware enabled, Django caches the rendered template. When the next request is made, Django checks the cache for the template, and if it exists, it returns a 304 Not Modified rather than the normal 200 Found HTTP response. That tells your browser to pull it from its cache instead of pulling it down from the server again. (It's a lot more complicated than this in practice, but I'm simplifying).

Long and short, is this is how caching in Django works. If you don't want this behavior, then you can either disable the cache (not the cache middleware), by telling it to use the `DummyCache` backend:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}
```

This will result in Django always returning a 200 with a fresh copy because it can never find the cached copy. You can also add the following setting to settings.py:

```
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY = True
```

Then, if you're logged in (through admin or otherwise), the response will vary on that and always return a fresh copy. However, this will effect normal users of your site as well, if you have any public-facing login capability.

Comment: Not at all. This is ideal behavior. Sending proper 304 Not Modified response codes makes your site more efficient and better able to handle other requests. If only every site worked so well.